# Level Curves Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

How do I go about sketching the level curve $m(x,y) = \frac{y}{x^2 + 2y^2}$? I'm struggling to determine how to go about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust constant into the form
$$ \frac{y}{x^2+2y^2}=\frac{1}{4c} $$
Complete the square
$$ x^2+2 y^2-4cy=0,\quad x^2+2(y^2-2cy+c^2)=2 c^2 $$
$$ \frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{2 c})^2}+\frac{(y-c)^2}{c^2} =1 $$
an ellipse in its standard form.

Comment: how did you get 1/4c on the right?

Comment: It's just a substitution that happens to be convenient. $k$ is a constant in $m(x, y) = k$, so you can write it as $\frac{1}{4c}$ for some other constant $c$. You could just as easily complete the square in terms of $k$.

Comment: You can choose a constant for convenience of later geometrical interpretation. This is done by keeping in mind its physical dimension as well. . I have chosen the substitution so that the resulting three geometric parameters are identified relating them to the axes and ellipse center displacements.